# Swift: Global Var Declaration Unwanted

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables, initializer

```
import UIKit

var options = [String]()

var correctAns = Int()

var question : String


class quizController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var button4: UIButton!


    init() {

        question = "What quiz are you taking?"
        options = ["Medical", "Bollywood", "Math", "Trivia"]
        correctAns = 0



    }

    struct shuffle {

        var readyToAskQuestions : [quizController] {

            var questions = Array(arrayLiteral: question)
            questions.count = questionNum

            questions.shuffleInPlace()
            return questions
        }
        init() {




        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error in the global var question : string line that it needs to be initialed (**Global 'var' declaration requires an initializer expression or getter/setter specifier**).

If I do try to initialize it, however, I'm getting several errors in the struct:

- questions.count = questionNum -- Error: **Cannot assign to property: 'count' is a get-only property**.
- questions.shuffleInPlace -- Error: **'[String]' does not have a member named shuffleInPlace**.
- return questions -- Error: **Cannot convert return expression of type '@lvalue [String' to expected return type '[quizController]'**.

How could I restructure my code so that the global var gets initialized without running into these errors.

Comment: put a ? after `var question : String` like `var question : String?` for starters, you are declaring it as a non-optional type, yet it is null which isnt allowed

Comment: It fixes the global var error, but those 3 errors in the struct that I mentioned appear just as before. I forgot to mention that super.viewDidLoad() has a 'Declaration is only valid at file scope' error. I know what it means, but I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

1. questions.count = questionNum -- Error: Cannot assign to property: 'count' is a get-only property.
   **Reason:** Pretty much clear,array's count is a read only property. You cannot assign a value to it, and you dont need do also..
2. questions.shuffleInPlace -- Error: '[String]' does not have a member named shuffleInPlace
   **Reason:** `questions` is an array of `String`. Swift array does not have a method called `shuffleInPlace`.
3. return questions -- Error: Cannot convert return expression of type '@lvalue [String' to expected return type '[quizController]'.
   **Reason:** See the type of `readyToAskQuestions` array of `quizController` you defined it as a computable property. Its expecting [quizController] as return value instead you are returning [String] which is wrong.

Seems like you are very new to Swift. Could not make you clear all these things in this answer. Highly recommended to read Apple swift programming ebook.

Comment: I am, and this is my first app. Thanks.